# Using txt files for multiple choice questions

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently making a quiz through python and Tkinter. I’m trying to use txt files, one for my questions and one for my set of answers for the said question, as well as one for explanations for the answers. However, I’m not sure how to implement this into my code. I’m not sure how to retrieve a question from the txt file and represent it as a label while having the correct set of answers that are associated with that question and represent them as buttons for the user to choose. As well as display the text for the correct explanation for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function that do that. Something like:

```
def write_to_txt(path, my_word):
    with open(path, "w") as my_txt:
        my_txt.write(my_word)
```